# Component (created by Route) giving inst.render is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a PrivateRoute component that try to render a Component as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            loggedIn ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}
                />
            )}
    />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

And I use this component like this:

```js
<PrivateRoute loggedIn={!!token} path="/user" component={User} />
```

It gives me the error as the title. I wonder where could I go wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error do you receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unpacked the component that you passed to `PrivateRoute` as `component`:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => (
                        // HERE ^
```

but then you use `Component` (note the capital `C`) which is imported from `react` to render it.

```
<Component {...props} />
```

And that imported `Component` doesn't have any `render` method. Hence the error you get.

To fix you need to rename your unpacked `component` like the following:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Comp, loggedIn, ...rest }) => (
                              // HERE ^
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      loggedIn ? (
        <Comp {...props} />
    // HERE ^
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```